# Variations and column names

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, variations

During the propagation of a custom list of items (created with XML scheme based on a native list template), the fields of the target variation of the columns are delivered in the language of the source variant.

I would like the columns to be displayed in the language of the site even after the current spread of items.

PS: Here are two links on this topic:

http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.nl/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-listinstance.html
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/11/21/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-6-configuration-internals/